# Submitting to Journals - impact factor versus subject specialism

Tags: publications, advisor, impact-factor

I am coming to the end of my PhD in which I have been working under an NDA and not yet published anything directly from the thesis itself. Pretty soon we will be able to publish the work, and I am eager to get my chapters out there as papers.

I had eyeballed a journal within my field (a journal that I use/cite heavily) that I consider to be relevant and would give my paper great exposure to the people working in my field. I suggested this journal to my main supervisor, but they were dismissive due to a low impact factor of 2.31. They instead suggested going for more of a broad, catch-all journal with a factor of 4.57 that covers a lot of topics in my field albeit (in my opinion) not very thoroughly. Typically papers in that journal are not technical - the paper I want to publish would be technical and have my code/algorithm published alongside the manuscript for reproducibility.

So my question is what to do? The paper is primarily a new method, but also has a bunch of case studies alongside the method that tell their own story and are relevant in their own right.

If anyone is wondering, I am in Earth Sciences/Geophysics.

Comment: At least for academia, in general the higher impact factor papers you have in your resume the better. So, unless you think that your paper has no chance to be accepted in high-impact journal (so it's just a waste of time), I would suggest you to agree with your advisor. Keep in mind, that usually papers published in better journals are also better cited. The journals with broader audience are also more prestigious.

Comment: Do you have enough material for two papers? In particular, a paper with results for the general high impact journal, and a technical details type paper for the lower impact specialised journal.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! As for enough material for 2 papers, the answer is probably yes. I can take my model/method and present it fully with 2 case studies as a methods paper, and then perhaps present the detailed case study separately. 

I guess at this stage you're both right, early career I need to think of CV/prestige boosting